# iOS, Sort allKeys of NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, nsdictionary

**<-- Why have i been down voted? At least comment some reasoning**

---

I have an incoming JSON array which details consecutive & non-consecutive date periods.

An example:
<sub>(Please note, the root index values are for example clarity. The real data is just associative key-value)</sub>

```
[0] => '01/01/2015 - 05/01/2015' : ['01/01/2015',
                                    '02/01/2015', 
                                    '03/01/2015',
                                    '04/01/2015', 
                                    '05/01/2015'],
[1] => '01/02/2015 - 05/02/2015' : ['01/02/2015',
                                    '02/02/2015',
                                    '03/02/2015',
                                    '04/02/2015',
                                    '05/02/2015'],
[2] => '25/03/2015': '25/03/2015',
[3] => '01/04/2015': '01/04/2015'
```

My final intention is to display each associative key in a `UITableView`, where consecutive date cells (indexes `[0]` & `[1]` in the example), on select will segue to another `UITableView` listing each individual date of the consecutive block. Non-consecutive date cells, (index `[2]` & `[3]` in example) will not be selectable to the user as there is nothing more to see. savvy?

My issue is that i import the JSON array into both an `NSArray`, & `NSDictionary`. (The reader should be aware that arrays are ordered, where as dictionaries are not)

`NSArray` of the imported data is structured true. The issue is i have no way of displaying the keys in the first `UITableView`, from which the 2nd `UITableView` can be populated with the relating value.

I take an `NSArray` of `allKeys` of the `NSDictionary`, which gives me the structured array of the keys of the un-structured dictionary. This i can use to display in the first `UITableView`, however its representation of data structure is not true to the imported structure. Its all jumbled & different each time.

My question is how the hell do i do this? but i should imagine that question may not be specific enough.... so, How would i sort the `allKeys` array of the dictionary in date order?

If your thinking, "Well this is easy! just sort using a descriptor",

like this one...?

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
NSArray *descriptors=[NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor];
NSArray *reverseOrder=[self.dateKeys sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Sadly, that would be too easy. That works fine with non-consecutive date keys, or single dates, but where i have consecutive date keys, `'01/01/2015 - 05/01/2015'` it fails. The overall `NSArray` is closer to the true imported data structure, but not close enough

Comment: Did you check the documentation for all the other ways to sort an array? Or do you rely completely on answers here, without any effort on your own? If so, do you think that might explain why you get voted down?

Comment: of course (at least to the best of my ability to understand apple's documentation). i feel there are a large number of people who feel a vote, up or down needs no explanation or reasoning. the logic of how this benefits anyone in the community eludes me. aside from that, i appreciate your comment regardless if you were the original down voter or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map the response into an `NSArray`, where each item is an `NSDictionary` with a key (the range) and either an `NSArray` of values (the dates) or an `NSString` (single date).

Example:

```
NSArray *data = @[
                  @{
                      @"01/01/2015 - 05/01/2015" : @[
                                                        @"01/01/2015",
                                                        @"02/01/2015",
                                                        @"03/01/2015",
                                                        @"04/01/2015",
                                                        @"05/01/2015"
                                                    ]
                  },
                  @{
                      @"25/03/2015" : @"25/03/2015"
                  }
                ];
```

Then, you can fill the first `UITableView` from the the main array, so from each item in the array, you get the dictionary key.

```
NSMutableArray *table1Data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:data.count];
for (NSDictionary *dateRange in data) {
    [table1Data addObject:[[dateRange allKeys] firstObject]];
}
```

And the second `UITableView` is filled from the value of the dictionary (array of dates) of the selected item in the main array, only when the value is an `NSArray`:

```
id table2Data = [[data[selectedIndex] allValues] firstObject];
if ([table2Data isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    // Navigate to second view, passing table2Data as the second table view data.
    // Cast table2Data to an NSArray if needed.
}
else {
    // Do not navigate to the second view
}
```

Comment: i'm looking into both yours & Ankit's answers. but yours has grabbed my attention first. It does make sense to solve the ordering issue at the point of structure disruption, as opposed to later when the dictionary has been assigned. (ignoring mutables). i look to using either isKindOfClass, or containsCharactersInRange (something like that) to determine the content. will update

Comment: @Simon.: have updated the answer to show how can you decide whether the item contains a range of dates (NSArray) or a single entry (NSString), so you can decide when to navigate to the second view with the second table view. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I read you correctly, you want to show one TableView with the date ranges (keys) in chronological order as follows:

```
Row 1: 01/01/2015 - 05/01/2015
Row 2: 01/02/2015 - 05/02/2015
Row 3: 25/03/2015
Row 4: 01/04/2015
```

And then, when tapping into row 1 or 2, show all the dates in the range in another TableView, i.e. for Row 1:

```
Row 1: 01/01/2015
Row 2: 02/01/2015
Row 3: 03/01/2015
Row 4: 04/01/2015
Row 5: 05/01/2015
```

You do need to store this data in an `NSDictionary *dateRanges` but as you are dealing with strings you need to encapsulate these date ranges in new classes which will make it easier to sort their values.

For instance, you may have a `DateRange` class with two `@properties` of type `NSDate`: `startDate` and `endDate`, where `endDate` is `nil` for those single dates (i.e. 25/03/2015) . You can then use an `NSSortDescriptor` to sort by `startDate` for the `[dateRanges allKeys]`:

```
NSArray *dateKeys = [self.dateRanges allKeys];
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:NO];
NSArray *reverseOrder = [dateKeys sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[ descriptor ]];
```